# Primary screen turns off after disconnecting external monitor

Tags: display, hdmi, monitor

I have a Dell external monitor connected to my ASUS UX305UA laptop. I use HDMI port, which is connected to HDMI-VGA converter, which connects to the monitor.

When I turn on my laptop and connect the monitor, the monitor shows stuffs normally, but when I move my cursor to the external monitor, it sometimes freezes. I got around this problem by connecting monitor before I turn on my laptop.

But then when I disconnect this monitor, the monitor of course turns off, but my primary screen also turns off. I think my laptop is turned on because the power button LED is on, but it's probably frozen because when I increase the volume I don't hear any sound.

The only way to make this not happen is to turn off the laptop before I disconnect monitor. Then I'd have to turn the laptop on again.

Is there a way to make this not happen? If that's not possible, is there a way to "eject" hdmi port, just like you eject USB drive before you pull it off? Maybe trying this would solve the problem.

Specs:

[uname -a and lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOiB6.png)

[xrandr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGNiO.png)

Comment: There are a few things you can try: 1. switch driver (which are available?) 2. Not sure if it works, but switching off the monitor by `xrandr` before disconnecting might help:  `xrandr --output HDMI1 --off`

Comment: Yeah so I treid turning off with xrandr, what happens is that my primary screen also turns off! It's as if my primary screen is dependent upon the external monitor
edit: my display setting - http://imgur.com/r9FbVVU

Comment: I think you need to switch driver, if possible...

Comment: Can you maybe describe more about how to switch driver?

Comment: If you open Software & updates, in one of the tabs you see "Extra drivers". Here is a list of available drivers, from which you can try another one. This is a bit tricky though, some drivers might cause major problems, so please backup important stuff first.